# How to suppress template-parts in undescores?

Tags: php, templates

I'm a newbie in English, and in creating my own WordPress theme.
So I need your help.

I used Underscores, to help me create my own theme.
And I have a problem with my templates:

Underscores use, for example, page.php with a part of the code in the file called template-parts.

The code for page.php is

```
<div id="template-right-sidebar" class="content-area">
        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;

        endwhile; // End of the loop.

</div><!-- #template-right-sidebar -->
```

And  the code of content-page.php in the template-parts file is :

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

<header class="entry-header">
    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->

<div class="entry-content">
    <?php
        the_content();

        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', '_-julie-cottet-web' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
    ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->

<?php get_sidebar();?>

<?php if ( get_edit_post_link() ) : ?>
    <footer class="entry-footer"></footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
<?php endif; ?>

</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

(Ok, there is more code in reality, but I wanted to make my question more simple.)

The thing is I don't wan't to use the file template-parts.
So I want to "copy" the code which is in content-page.php directly in page.php

I must to it wrong, because it is not working. And I don't know why...

What I did :

```
    <div id="template-right-sidebar" class="content-area">
    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>

        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

             // AND ALL THE REST OF THE CODE 

         </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

        <?php // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
            comments_template();
        endif;

     endwhile; // End of the loop.

        </div><!-- #template-right-sidebar -->
```

What is my mistake ?
How can I do that ?

Thanks for reading and for your help !

Answer (score 1):

First of all a simple advice if you are a complete beginner: i suggest you start from scratch with a tutorial that step by step takes you to create a theme. That way you will have a better understanding on how it works. Underscores is great i use it my self but if you are a total newbie, it could be more difficult to start with.

Do you have WP_DEBUG set to true in your wp-config.php file? If not go on the main directory of you Wordpress install and add

`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

It will allow you to see errors and help you identify what is the problem.
Here i reproduced my working page.php using Underscores

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site may use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package sample
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">

        <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

                <?php // YOUR CONTENT AND TEMPLATE for PAGES GOES HERE ?>

            </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->



            <?php 
            // get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );
            // as you can see i just copied the content of content-page.php here
            // and commented out the get_template_part function
            // you can delete this, it is just to explain a little more ;)
            ?>

            <?php

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;

        endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I don't know what I did wrong the first time, but now it is working... I think I just forgot a ?> the first time somewhere...

Comment: Classic eheh! Happy if i was able to help you solve this. Tag this answer as problem solving ;) have a good one :)